# After onActivityResult() the imageView added dynamically disappears

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on an application where I can add image selected by user from device picture gallery to imageview Dynamically to the layout. When one image is added everything works perfect. When I try to add another image the 1st image is lost from the layout. I dont know why it is happening please give me the solution for it.
When the gallery is opened onStop method is called. Does this means that the activity is recreated. ?
Here's the code of `onActivityResult()`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
                    final DragImageView dynamicImgView = new DragImageView(
                            getApplicationContext(), yourSelectedImage);
                     final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    dynamicImgView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    relativeLayout.addView(dynamicImgView);
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Code where i have created the Imageview Dynamically.

```
public class DragImageView extends ImageView{

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private float mDeltaX;
    private float mDeltaY; 
    private Bitmap bmpImg;

    public DragImageView(Context context, Bitmap bmpImg) {
        super(context);
        this.bmpImg = bmpImg;   
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DragImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        setImageBitmap(bmpImg);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();

                mLastTouchX = event.getRawX();
                mLastTouchY = event.getRawY();

                switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                    mDeltaX = mLastTouchX - lParams.leftMargin;
                    mDeltaY = mLastTouchY - lParams.topMargin;

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    mLastTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    mLastTouchY = event.getRawY();

                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                    params.leftMargin = (int) (mLastTouchX - mDeltaX);
                    params.topMargin = (int) (mLastTouchY - mDeltaY);
                    setLayoutParams(params);

                    break;
                }
                }
                invalidate();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: when you add dynamic view to relative layout you have to gave some reference for currently adding view to previous added view.

Comment: Didn't get what you saying, can you please explain. I am new to android.

Comment: if you don't wan to do any other changes then just change your RelativeLayout to LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Comment: Any specific reason for doing that.

Comment: reason is you not required more changes in your existing code.

Comment: @Haresh i have edited my answer..i have checked the new answer and it was working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

your code under `If` condition should have something like this

```
   if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
           final DragImageView dynamicImgView = new DragImageView(
                      getApplicationContext(), yourSelectedImage);
                 final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                 if(relativeLayout.getChildCount()>0){
                    int lastChild = relativeLayout.getChildCount();
                     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,relativeLayout.getChildAt(lastChild-1).getId());
                   }
                dynamicImgView.setLayoutParams(params);
                relativeLayout.addView(dynamicImgView);
            }
```

Comment: The imageView is not added itself

Comment: plz explain what do you mean by `The imageView is not added itself`.

Comment: you should have to provide relative position to the next `ImageView` added in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: When I select the image from the gallery that Image is set to ImageView and that imageView is added to the layout. That imageView is not Visible on the layout by the code help you have provided.

Comment: if your `relativeLayout` contains only `DragImageView` type object as child then the code will work definitely, otherwise you have to check how many image you have added and where the next image will be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

// define this variable for dynamic ImageView id in activity.
    int imageViewId=1;

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                    if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
                        final DragImageView dynamicImgView = new DragImageView(
                                getApplicationContext(), yourSelectedImage);
                        dynamicImgView.setId(imageViewId++);
                        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        if(imageViewId>1){
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,imageViewId-1);
                        }
                        dynamicImgView.setLayoutParams(params);
                        relativeLayout.addView(dynamicImgView);
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks mate for the help.. But dint work. Still getting only one image.